Ubuntu fails to load
I am trying to load Ubuntu as a dual boot with Windows 11 on a Dell Latitude 5290 2 in 1 touch.
It fails to load when almost complete. The error message is "something went wrong with the installation" and I allow it to report the problem.
I have used Balena as instructed and tried various releases.
I Am using a USB and have tried versions 24.04.1 and 24.1
I have removed the failed partitions but still get failures.
I would appreciate any advice, thank you.

What is the error message?

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You've provided no clues as to what Ubuntu product, nor release of that product you attempted to install; nor any checks you performed to rule out atypical errors.

I have added the requested info

Ubuntu releases are year.month in format so 24.04 tells us its the 2024-April release; but there was no release in January (no 24.01) nor in fact on any year in the last two decades; but even then for 24.04 there were many products (Server, Desktop, Cloud, as well as flavors;; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/08/30/ubuntu-24-04-1-lts-released/) with 3 installers (selected at download time by ISO used) for 24.04, so 24.04 details are somewhat unclear and the invalid 24.01 release makes no sense  (there was a release this month; ie. 24.10 or 2024-October so do you mean that?)

Older version of Ubuntu but otherwise similar: Dell Latitude 5290  Dell normally releases any unique drivers so kernel & drivers for a distribution a year or so after release of system should have all the drivers you need. Often settings in UEFI, or Windows bitlocker, fast startup, or needing chkdsk also cause issues.
